# How to move GRUB installation to a different partition?

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, mbr

I have a laptop for work. I originally had Windows 7 on it then I installed Linux Mint 17 to dual boot.

During my installation of Mint 17 I accidentally installed GRUB on the wrong partition (sda2). Now when I try and log into Windows for my work, it brings me right back to the Grub boot screen.

Is there any way to move GRUB from one partition to another? Which would the correct partition to install GRUB? Perhaps using a live DVD or something like System Rescue CD or Parted Magic etc.?

I need to access both Windows 7 and Linux Mint. As a normal standard dual boot.

I have attached my boot information which I got using bootinfoscript [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8349199/)

Comment: did you installed Mint in `/dev/sda6` partition?

Comment: @KasiyA Yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this, http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/, in the past, I believe thats what your looking for, it allows you to choose which partition to install/repair grub on. It even has a option to restore windows master boot record.

You could also try windows repair cd, heres a safe copy I have used myself, https://kickass.to/windows-7-repair-discs-32-bit-and-64-bit-iso-t8147350.html#main

Comment: @Stoan, I can almost guarantee you can get it working using the 2 disks I provided you. Rescatux is a GUI, so just give it a shot.

Comment: I want to give a try, I downloaded Rescatux iso but how do I put it to the USB? I tried using pendrivelinux but I got an error or should I just burn it to a CD?

Comment: @Stoan, I have never used pendrivelinux before, but I have created bootable .iso before using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) .     I personally used the cd myself when using rescatux last but I don't see why it would matter because either way it's running live. Try UNetbootin and if that doesn't work try the CD. Once rescatux loads, the grub/windows boot repairs options should pop up automatically.http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/rescatux_rescapp_main_menu.png

Comment: Rescatux's Boot Repair did the trick, Thank You so much @Skateguy :-)

Comment: @Stoan, great to hear it. I'm sure it was a good feeling seeing windows load again. Did you have to use a cd or were you able to use a bootable usb?

Comment: It sure was, after weeks of struggling :-), I was able to make a bootable USB, using the default "USB Image Writer" that comes with Linux Mint. Thanks again.